# could some explain me this permuation/derangement program

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

Hi can some one please explain me the below derangement/permutation program in a simple way.

From past one week I am banging my head to understand the program. I have understood all the methods but I am not able to understand the **"else part"**. I have tried debugging the program but didn't get clarity to what is happening in the else part.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Deranged {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int num = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number :" + num);
        int size = digitSize(num);
        System.out.println("Size :" + size);
        System.out.println("Permutation :" + fact(size));
        int swap = fact(size);
        int array[] = digitArray(num, size);
        if (size < 3) {
            if (size < 2) {
                System.out.print(num);
            } else {
                System.out.println(array[0] + "" + array[1]);
                System.out.println(array[1] + "" + array[0]);
            }
        } else {    // NEED CLARITY FROM HERE
            int i = 2;
            for (int outer = 0; outer <= size - 1; outer++) {
                int fix = array[0];
                for (int j = 1; j <= swap / size; j++) {
                    if (i == size) {
                        i = 2;
                    }
                    int temp = array[i - 1];
                    array[i - 1] = array[i];
                    array[i] = temp;
                    i++;
                    int uniqueNo = fix;
                    for (int k = 1; k < size; k++) {
                        uniqueNo = (uniqueNo * 10) + array[k];
                    }
                    System.out.println(j + ": " + uniqueNo);
                }
                int t = array[0];
                if ((outer + 1) > size - 1) {
                    array[0] = array[outer];
                    array[outer] = t;
                } else {
                    array[0] = array[outer + 1];
                    array[outer + 1] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int fact(int num) {
        int factNo = 1;
        for (int i =num; i > 0; i--) 
        {
            factNo = factNo * i;
        }
        return factNo;
    }

    public static int digitSize(int num) {

        //int count = String.valueOf(num).length();
        // return count;
        int count = 0;
        while(num>0)
        {
            num/=10;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int[] digitArray(int num, int size) {
        int count[] = new int[size];
        int i = size - 1, rem;
        while (num > 0) {
            rem = num % 10;
            count[i] = rem;
            num = num / 10;
            i--;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can any one explain me this part please?

`int uniqueNo = fix; for (int k = 1; k < size; k++) 
{ uniqueNo = (uniqueNo * 10) + array[k]; } 
System.out.println(j + ": " + uniqueNo);`

Answer (score 3):

In the code *size* is the number of digits in your number and *swap* is the factorial of the number of digits. For example, if you enter a 5 digit number the *fact* function calculates 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1. *array* is just a list of the digits you entered, ordered from the least significant digit to the most significant.

So here is the pseudo code for the case where the number of digits is 3 or greater. I've interleaved the code to make it clearer.

i = 2
 For each digit in the array of digits indexed by outer
 - Set fix to the digit currently stored in the first element of the array

```
       int i = 2;
        for (int outer = 0; outer <= size - 1; outer++) {
            int fix = array[0];
```

For each index j from 1 to the factorial of the number of digits divided by number of digits
- If i is equal to the number of digits, set i equal to 2
- Swap digit i-1 with digit i in the digit array
- Increment I

```
            int fix = array[0];
            for (int j = 1; j <= swap / size; j++) {
                if (i == size) {
                    i = 2;
                }
                int temp = array[i - 1];
                array[i - 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
                i++;
```

Set uniqueNo to the decimal number that the digit array currently represents, except that fix is the least significant digit
Print the uniqueNo for the current value of j

```
                int uniqueNo = fix;
                for (int k = 1; k < size; k++) {
                    uniqueNo = (uniqueNo * 10) + array[k];
                }
                System.out.println(j + ": " + uniqueNo);
```

If the current value of outer is the last element in the digit array
- Swap the first digit with the last digit in the array
Else
- Swap the first digit of the array with the digit at outer+1

```
           int t = array[0];
            if ((outer + 1) > size - 1) {
                array[0] = array[outer];
                array[outer] = t;
            } else {
                array[0] = array[outer + 1];
                array[outer + 1] = t;
            }
```

The code is basically iterating factorial/number of digit times for each digit of the number that was input and rearranging the digits with each iteration in a way that wraps around from the last digit to the first. It's difficult to understand partly because the variable names are uninformative.

The number of permutations of n distinct objects is n! (factorial), so the code is just listing all possible permutations of the digits of the number that was input. If there are only 2 digits, there are only two permutations, and of course 1 digit has only one permutation, so those are special cases. If you iterate through each digit, the maximum number of permutations keeping one digit "fixed" is factorial/number of digits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Any Idea how can I make this code permute and print the list of values starting with zeros ?

Comment: `int uniqueNo = fix;`
`for (int k = 1; k < size; k++) {`
`uniqueNo = (uniqueNo * 10) + array[k];`
`}`
`System.out.println(j + ": " + uniqueNo);`  You didn't explain this part